# Aggregate Ordering with Named Association

Tags: vhdl, aggregates

I'm struggling to understand the bit order of an aggregate, especially since I've used name association.

The buses are defined as `(0 to 3)` and `(3 downto 0)`, but since I've used named association, why are the outputs `z3..0` and `ob3..0` the reverse of each other? Why is `outputs_b` the reverse of `z_bus`? Why did assigning `outputs_b` from the constant array make a difference to the bit ordering as compared to assigning `z_bus` from a literal?

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Test_TB is
end entity;

architecture V1 of Test_TB is
    type TLogicLevel is (L, H, X);
    type TOutputs is array(natural range<>) of TLogicLevel;
    type TOutputsTable is array(natural range<>) of TOutputs;

    constant OUTPUTS_TABLE: TOutputsTable :=
    (
        (3 => H,  2 => H,  1 => H,  0 => L),
        (3 => X,  2 => X,  1 => X,  0 => X)  -- Added this because it can't compile an array with a single element.
    );

    signal outputs_a: TOutputs(0 to 3);
    signal outputs_b: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
    signal oa0, oa1, oa2, oa3: TLogicLevel;
    signal ob0, ob1, ob2, ob3: TLogicLevel;

    signal y_bus: TOutputs(0 to 3);
    signal z_bus: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
    signal y0, y1, y2, y3: TLogicLevel;
    signal z0, z1, z2, z3: TLogicLevel;

begin

    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        y_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L);              -- Performs bit-for-bit copy.
        z_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L);              -- Performs bit-for-bit copy. NOT REVERSED.
        outputs_a <= OUTPUTS_TABLE(0);                          -- Performs bit-for-bit copy.
        outputs_b <= OUTPUTS_TABLE(0);                          -- Performs bit-reverse copy. IS REVERSED.
        wait for 10 ns;
        (3 => oa3, 2 => oa2, 1 => oa1, 0 => oa0) <= outputs_a;  -- Performs bit-for-bit copy.
        (3 => ob3, 2 => ob2, 1 => ob1, 0 => ob0) <= outputs_b;  -- Performs bit-reverse copy of a reverse copy, i.e. reverse reverse.
        wait for 10 ns;
        (3 => y3, 2 => y2, 1 => y1, 0 => y0) <= y_bus;          -- Performs bit-for-bit copy.
        (3 => z3, 2 => z2, 1 => z1, 0 => z0) <= z_bus;          -- Performs bit-reverse copy of non-reverse copy. So z3..0 is the reverse of ob3..0.
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is behaving as I would expect.

```
signal y_bus: TOutputs(0 to 3);
signal z_bus: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
...
y_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L);  
z_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L);
```

For `y_bus` the left hand bit is `0`, which you have set to `L`. 
For `z_bus` the left hand bit is `3`, which you have set to `H`. CHECK.

```
constant OUTPUTS_TABLE: TOutputsTable :=
(
    (3 => H,  2 => H,  1 => H,  0 => L),
...
signal outputs_a: TOutputs(0 to 3);
signal outputs_b: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
....
outputs_a <= OUTPUTS_TABLE(0);
outputs_b <= OUTPUTS_TABLE(0);
```

For `OUTPUTS_TABLE(0)` the left hand bit is `0`, which you have set to `L`. For `outputs_a` the left hand bit is `0`, so you would expect that to be `L`. For `outputs_b` the left hand bit is `3`, so you would expect that to be `L`.  CHECK.

```
signal outputs_a: TOutputs(0 to 3);
signal outputs_b: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
...
(3 => oa3, 2 => oa2, 1 => oa1, 0 => oa0) <= outputs_a;
(3 => ob3, 2 => ob2, 1 => ob1, 0 => ob0) <= outputs_b;
```

For `outputs_a` the left hand bit is `0`, so you would expect `oa0` to be `L`, because it is that that is one the left hand side. For `outputs_b` the left hand bit is `3`, so you would expect `ob0` to be `L`, because it is that that is one the left hand side. CHECK. But hang on, why are `oa0` and `ob0` the left hand side? Because that is how the bits in the aggregates `(3 => oa3, 2 => oa2, 1 => oa1, 0 => oa0)` and `(3 => ob3, 2 => ob2, 1 => ob1, 0 => ob0)` will be numbered, because the index type will be an `integer` and `integer` types count up.

```
signal y_bus: TOutputs(0 to 3);
signal z_bus: TOutputs(3 downto 0);
....
y_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L); 
z_bus <= (3 => H, 2 => H, 1 => H, 0 => L); 
....
(3 => y3, 2 => y2, 1 => y1, 0 => y0) <= y_bus;
(3 => z3, 2 => z2, 1 => z1, 0 => z0) <= z_bus;
```

So, as we already know, for `y_bus` the left hand bit is `0`, which you have set to `L` and for `z_bus` the left hand bit is `3`, which you have set to `H`. So, you would expect `y0` (the left hand bit) to be `L` and `z0` (the left hand bit) to be `H`. CHECK.

My head hurts.

Comment: "For `outputs_b` the left hand bit is `3`, so you would expect that to be `L`." I disagree because I've used named association to set bit `3` to `H` irrespective of whether it is at the left hand or right hand of the vector. I can't see the difference between the assignment to `z-bus` and the assignment to `outputs_b`. To my way of thinking, the left/right handedness shouldn't make any difference because named association overrides it as with `z_bus`. So why not with `outputs_b`?

Comment: I get it! `outputs_b <= OUTPUTS_TABLE(0);` is equivalent to `outputs_b <= (L, H, H, H);` not `outputs_b <= (0 => L, 1 => H, 2 => H, 3 => H);` Thank you.